# jvisualvm: visualgc histogram

Tags: plugins, windows-7-x64, jvisualvm

Does anyone know why I'v got error

**Not supported for this JVM**

when I run Visual GC plugin?

Bellow about information from jvisualvm

```
Version:    1.8.0 (Build 1360-130911); platform 20130911-unknown-revn
System:     Windows 7 (6.1) Service Pack 1, amd64 64bit
Java:   1.8.0; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.0-b70, mixed mode)
Vendor:     Oracle Corporation, http://java.oracle.com/
Environment:    Cp1250; pl_PL (visualvm)
User directory:     C:\Users\tech\AppData\Roaming\VisualVM\7u60
Cache directory:    C:\Users\tech\AppData\Local\VisualVM\Cache\7u60
Clusters:   "C:\Java\jdk1.8.0\lib\visualvm\platform
C:\Java\jdk1.8.0\lib\visualvm\visualvm
C:\Java\jdk1.8.0\lib\visualvm\profiler"
```

Answer (score 3):

If it is the visualgc histogram, there is some discussion here that says

> The Histogram view may or may not be displayed by default depending on
>   the application configuration - when the monitored VM uses Parallel
>   Scavenge collection (using Server VM or setting -XX:+UseParallelGC or
>   -XX:+AggressiveHeap), Histogram view is hidden by default.

https://blogs.oracle.com/nbprofiler/entry/visual_gc_plugin_2_0

If it is visualgc itself, then it requires jstatd running, see here for help on how to setup jstatd on the remote server:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/visualgc-136680.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jstatd.html